# how to pass variable from plugin php to another php file in wordpress using session/function or javascript?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have oneplugin file testplugin.php..It contains variable $abc;

//main plugin.php

```
if(!is_admin()){
new Funtion_Button();
}
class Function_Button
{

if(is_single() || is_page() || is_home() ){  
      global $post; 
      global $wpdb; 

 $query_images_args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment' , 'post_mime_type' =>'image','post_status' => 'published', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'numberposts' => 1

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
         $images = array();
         foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
         $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

         }
                 $abc[]=0;
         $abc= $abc.http_build_query($images);
                 $_SESSION['arrayImg']=$abc;
 );
}
```

///recieving file

```
include ('testplugin.php'); 
session_start();
$array1[]=$abc;
```

Now this $abc is from main plugin page

But i am getting this error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\testplugin.php on line 98**

on 98 line i have  *`if(!is_admin()){`*

Comment: Read this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is_admin-what-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using session :

//On testplugin.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;
```

//On another file

```
session_start();
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Using cookies :

//On testplugin.php

```
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;
```

//On page 2

```
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

Comment: Thanks @pranshu it worked ..I dont need to include that testplugin.php on second page??

Comment: @user1145009 no, you don't need to include testplugin.php on the next page, as you are using cookies, and session, the values of cookies and session are stored temporarily in the browser. so no need to include the for passing this variable.

Comment: ..I was trying in localhost it worked..But now then i have made it online on wordpress theme ..The sesion variable is not stored ..