# I need to pass a variable between files using PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created two plugins. Plugin A gets the latest posts, all of them. It has an option that can remove posts by entering their ID, this is accessible via the shortcode or directly in functions.php. This works.

Plugin B gets the most popular posts using an internal analytics systems. I have a variable called `$most_popular_ids` which contains all of the post ID's of the highest viewed posts for that particular category. So `$most_popular_ids` changes depending on which page it is on. This works.

These are displayed side by side on the main pages of the website. So ideally I would like them to not show duplicate posts.

What I finally need to do is pass `$most_popular_ids` from plugin B to plugin A or to functions.php. This will allow me to exclude all of the most popular posts from the latest posts.

Obviously making the variable global only works in the scope of the file so that won't work. I tried creating a $_SESSION but you can't do that in Wordpress as far as I know. Most of the stuff in the plugins can't be redeclared so my include attempts didn't work either :\

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Thanks for offering a BTC bounty, but they are discouraged here. If the question is on-topic, and not too broad, you should get help for free `:)`.

Comment: So you want to filter "most popular posts" from list of  "Latest posts" ?? and do not require BTC bounty please.

Comment: Not sure if awarding a financial bounty is in tune with the site's policies. If you _are_ willing to pay, why not spend the money on some book or to hire somebody to do the work for you?

Comment: @halfer: I'm unsure as to what the official rules/guidelines are concerning financial bounties, and so flagged the question for a mod to look at it, so I thought it best to leave the question as-is until a mod had seen it

Comment: @halfer what about 10 virtual cookies or one really cool internet fist bump :P

Comment: why didn't you use a temp file or cookie(a encoded one)?

Comment: Check Out This:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874726/how-to-pass-variable-from-plugin-php-to-another-php-file-in-wordpress-using-sess

Comment: @MSS Thanks mate, with a few slight modifications, I got it to work. Legend!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use sessions in WordPress, but it would probably be easier to use the `wp_cache_set()` and `wp_cache_get()` functions

For example, in Plugin B you would do something like:

```
wp_cache_set('mykey_most_popular_ids', $most_popular_ids);
```

Then in Plugin A or your functions file you can do:

```
$most_popular_ids = wp_cache_get('mykey_most_popular_ids);
```

Obviously you'd need to make sure the function in Plugin B sets the cache entry before trying to get it in Plugin A of the functions file

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using filters. In plugin A, implement a filter that allows to set the `post__not_in` param of the query:

```
$query_args = array();

$post__not_in = apply_filters( 'check_for_most_popular_ids', false );

if( $post__not_in && is_array( $post__not_in ) )
    $query_args['post__not_in'] = $post__not_in;

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

In plugin B, hook into the filter and pass the most popular IDs:

```
add_filter( 'check_for_most_popular_ids', 'send_most_popular_ids', 10, 1 );
function send_most_popular_ids( $post__not_in = false )
{
    $most_popular_ids = get_most_popular_ids(); // returns array of IDs OR false

    if( $most_popular_ids )
        return $most_popular_ids;

    return $post__not_in;
}
```